# What should be appropriate adjective here (worst to worse)?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-choice, adjectives, comparative-degree

His condition got from worst to worse.
Now to correct sentence i'll use worse to worst but for implying that his condition got better should i use well??

Comment: It is more idiomatic to say "His condition went from bad to worse." But if 'he' is getting better it is entirely wrong to use 'worse' or 'worst' at all.

Comment: Then what should be correct sentence. His condition got from (ill condition) to (better condition)

Comment: @WeatherVane: A bit more than just "more idiomatic"! OP's *from worst to worse* simply doesn't make sense, and for most speakers / listeners it would be impossible to distinguish ***worse to*** from ***worst to*** anyway. But you're quite right that the standard idiomatic usage is ***from bad to worse***, and there's no equivalent for going in the opposite direction (to "improve" from being ***worse than bad*** to simply being ***bad*** again).

Comment: @GoogleGoggle: There is no "correspondingly opposite" idiomatic usage for this context. He (or "his condition") got better, recovered, improved,...

Comment: Ok so i should use improve,recovered. Thanks for ur valuable comments

Comment: He is on the road to recovery.

Comment: "His condition got better."

Answer (score 1):

The commonly used phrase is

**worse and worse** * and the opposite is* **better and better**. "

> Since he has been in the UK, his English gets better and better."

better and better (idiomatic) continually improving Ref [Word Sense](https://www.wordsense.eu/better_and_better/)